# Springboot Docker Windows7

Tags: windows, docker, spring-boot, windows-7, 64-bit

I created the simplest basic spring-boot hellow world application and tried to run it on docker. However I am getting error. Below are more details --

OS- Windows 7, 64 bit

Docker version : Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

Springboot version: 1.5.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot.docker</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>spring-boot-docker</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
ADD target/spring-boot-docker.jar spring-boot-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","spring-boot-docker.jar"]
```

My application.properties

```
server.port=8082
```

My java classes

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDockerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDockerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

I tested this application by running it locally and when I hit: http://localhost:8082/hello I see expected message "Hi"

I then did mvn clean install to create target jar of my application.
Then I launched "Docker Quickstart Terminal" on my windows machine. 
After that I went to directory where my code lies and from there I ran below command::

```
docker build . -t spring-boot-docker
```

When I check docker images I can see new image created spring-boot-docker.

After that I run below command to create container from that image

```
docker run --name springbootdocker -d spring-boot-docker:latest
```

I can see container created using command: "docker ps"
I also checked "docker logs springbootdocker"

THen I tried to hit URL:
http://localhost:8082/hello

I am getting error message as :

**This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8082 hello
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Is it something known issue running docker on windows?

Do I need to change Dockerfile to run that in ubuntu or something like that?

Comment: You have to publish the port.  Add a -P to publish all exposed ports or check into -p for custom mappings.

Comment: @user2105103 how do we do custom mapping using -p ? Can you give an example or send me sample command

Comment: I tried this command: docker run -P --name springbootdocker -d spring-boot-docker:latest   This didn't help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer was simple.
Though everything is happening on windows, the underlying OS is Linux, so we have to replace localhost by ip address of linux machine of VM
so instead of hitting: http://localhost:8082/hello 
I had to hit:  http://192.168.99.100:8082/hello